# Где находятся настройки FOGa (тумана) в Unity 2020?

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-ui

Пытался найти наcтройки FOGa там же, где и в Unity 2019.4 в Rendering -> Lightning Settings, но безуспешно

Comment: в Rendering -> Lihtning Settings есть Fog. он находится в Other Settings, первый же. [мой скрин](https://sun9-51.userapi.com/impg/cXQ_G6HJiOt09tXWVS_r9gPSg-fpQY-dghqDIg/up2uHtTnyx8.jpg?size=475x627&quality=96&proxy=1&sign=e383188633763f594141bacf6f8b1eca&type=album)

Answer (score 0):

Судя по документации юнити - сейчас туман добавляется через пост-процессинг. А для постпроцессинга нужно качать необходимый тебе ассет.

В документации при переключении версии с 2019.3 на 2019.4 тебя перенаправляет на общую страницу пост-процессинга и там среди списка пост-процесов есть и туман, собственно.

Если не используешь HDR то смотри в "Deferred Fog" обычного ассета постпроцессинга, вот документация к нему  https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.postprocessing@3.0/manual/Deferred-Fog.html